# Core Plot 0.4 tutorial iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

Does anyone have a good tutorial/book recommendation for using Core Plot 0.4 in iOS. I have never used it before and from looking at the tutorials that they have linked to it does not make sense. I can't even run the [Switch on the code tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application). Where do I start?

Comment: Have you looked at the example apps included with Core Plot?

Comment: It is better use version 0.9 of core plot. Many bugs are fixed there

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to go with Core Plot 0.9, this tutorial is the most up-to-date one I have found:

http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/10/adding-charts-to-your-iphone-ipad-app-using-core-plot/

My only reservation about it is that his code seems a bit verbose for an introductory tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This link( http://allforiphone.sosblog.com/All-for-iPhone-b1/CorePlot-For-You-b1-p11.htm ) may help you adding core plot project with your project. To use the library you can check out the example provided by the creators. It is quite good.