# How to draw simple line graph and bar graph using Core Plot framework in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, core-plot

I am new to core Plot framework. I want to draw line graph and bar graph in iPhone. I searched for samples in Google but, i can not find exact samples/tutorials. Can you please guide some samples or tutorials using Core-Plot framework and draw graph? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any examples for how to draw a line chart in Core Plot on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934357/are-there-any-examples-for-how-to-draw-a-line-chart-in-core-plot-on-the-iphone)

Comment: The Core Plot framework itself comes with several examples of bar and line graphs, so you should look there first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples and demo code:

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/#hg%2Fexamples

Tutorials:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Duplicate question:

[Core Plot 0.4 tutorial iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123880/core-plot-0-4-tutorial-ios)

Answer (score 0):

A nice example how to draw the graph: http://www.mobdevel.com/?p=96

The documentation is provided here: http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/MacOS/annotated.html